# Dump content of nested items

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have a database with authors and books. One author can have multiple books and one book can have multiple authors, so many to many scheme. Goal is the have a REST API using sqlalchemy and marshmallow:

```
secondary_foo = db.Table('secondary_foo',
                            db.Column('author_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id')),
                            db.Column('book_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id')))

class Author(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'author'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))

class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'book'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    authors = db.relationship('Author', secondary="secondary_foo", backref='books', lazy="joined")

class AuthorSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Author

class BookSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    authors = ma.Nested(AuthorSchema, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

Now I add some authors and books:

```
authors_schema = AuthorSchema(many=True)
author_schema = AuthorSchema()
book_schema = BookSchema()

author = Author(name='Chuck Paluhniuk')
book = Book(title='Fight Club')
book.authors.append(author)
db.session.add(author)
db.session.add(book)
db.session.commit()

book1 = Book(title='Lord of the Rings')
book1.authors.append(author)
db.session.add(book1)
db.session.commit()

s = BookSchema(many=True)
a = AuthorSchema(many=True)

author1 = Author(name='Tolkien')
book1.authors.append(author1)
db.session.commit()
```

Now I want to print all authors and their books:

```
authors = Author.query.all()
print(authors_schema.dump(authors))
[{'books': [1, 2], 'id': 1, 'name': u'Chuck Paluhniuk'}, {'books': [2], 'id': 2, 'name': u'Tolkien'}]
```

However, I want to display directly the book title instead of the ids, e.g.:

```
[{'books': ['Fight Club', 'Lord of the Rings'], 'id': 1, 'name': u'Chuck Paluhniuk'}, {'books': ['Lord of the Rings'], 'id': 2, 'name': u'Tolkien'}]
```